# Perl:where am i committing mistake?

Tags: regex, perl

I am using cgi perl to be able to view the contents of a file on a browser.I have below requirement:

- All the lines starting with a word 'Service' must print as heading (H4)
- All the other lines must print as a paragraph (P).

I have tried below code, but it is not working. All the lines are getting printed as heading (H4). Am I commiting any mistake?

```
  use strict;
  use warnings;
  use diagnostics;
    printf "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
    print <<HTML;
       <HTML>
       <HEAD>
       <TITLE>DataPower_Status</TITLE>
      </HEAD>
        HTML

     open FILE, "dpstatus" or die "could not open filename";
      while(<FILE>) {
        if ($_^"Service")
   {
        printf "<TR><TD><H4>$_</H4></TD></TR>\n";
  }
   else {

        printf "<TR><TD><p>$_</p></TD></TR>\n";
       }
        }
   close FILE;

    print <<HTML;
   </body>
   </html>
    HTML
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
        if ($_^"Service")
```

does not use a regex at all; it's just the XOR operator `^` with the arguments `$_` and `"Service"`. So it's not at all what you want.

Instead, change it to this:

```
        if ($_ =~ m/^Service/)
```

or, more tersely, this:

```
        if (/^Service/)
```

Comment: Its working absolutely fine.Could you please explain why my code was not working? What exactly did you do in your code?

Comment: @user2607367: Re: why your code doesn't work: It's just that it has nothing to do with what you were trying to do. If you'll explain why you thought that your code *would* work, I can try to address your misconceptions . . . Re: what my code does: `$_ =~ m/^Service/` applies the regex `^Service` (meaning, "starts with `Service`") to the value of `$_`.

Comment: I am new to perl. So I thought using this bit of code `if ($_^"Service")` will solve my purpose. But, I did not use the regular expression correctly. Is there any defined/specific way of using regular expression in perl?

Comment: Yes. `m/regexp/` will _match_ and RE. `s/regex/replace/` will _replace_  like sed does. If you want to apply this to a particular variable (default is $_) you use `=~`. E.g. `if ( $variable =~ m/some_text/ );`

Comment: @user2607367: `($_^"Service")` is analogous to `($_+"Service")` or `($_||"Service")`: it's just the operator `^` with two arguments, `$_` and `"Service"`. There's nothing "regular expression" about it. (The `^` operator is a bitwise XOR.)

Answer (score 1):

```
$_^"Service"
```

From [`perldoc perlop`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Bitwise-Or-and-Exclusive-Or)

> Binary "^" returns its operands XORed together bit by bit.

so you probably want regex `/^Service/` instead of XOR operation.